# why there are lot of tun interfaces on my ubuntu 20.04 machine

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, nmcli

Today I ran `nmcli device show` and its showing lot of `tun` interfaces on my machine.
Also device name is not familiar to me like as0t0 other than eth0 and wl0.
Can I check who is using them. also is it save to remove them.

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         as0t0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           tun
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     as0t0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.27.224.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 172.27.224.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::36f0:2ea:69db:490/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         as0t1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           tun
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     as0t1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/7
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.27.225.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 172.27.225.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::abfe:7b9c:4ab2:ea70/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

Comment: You're not running an OpenVPN server by any chance and forgot about it, are you?

Comment: yes [+] openvpn. I have disabled that service but interfaces are still there. I do need open-vpn client but not openvpn server. So can I remove openvpn without disturbing my open-vpn client settings.

Comment: well, it seems easy enough to try!

Comment: i tried to remove it. but it messed up my client settings. though re-installation. Anyway thanks for pointing in right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my discussion the comments:

these are tun sockets of the OpenVPN server.